# Wishing for elegant ActiveRecord chaining

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rails-activerecord

In my Rails 3 app I got users that have:

- friends (and they are users, too)
- activities (via [PublicActivity](https://github.com/pokonski/public_activity))

There is an action where I need to display my friend's activities.

I wish to do it via chain like this (and my question is: **how can I do it?**):

```
@activities = current_user.friends.activities
```

But it won't work because `current_user.friends` returns an ActiveRecrord::Relation object.

```
undefined method `activities' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0xc4d7770>
```

I have to query them like this:

```
@activities = PublicActivity::Activity.where(owner_id: current_user.friend_ids)
```

It works okay, but it is not as elegant as I want it to be :)

So, is there a more elegant way to query friend's actions using chaining?

The User model look like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :friendships
  has_many :friends, through: :friendships  # 

  has_many :activities, class_name: "::PublicActivity::Activity", as: :owner
  # ...
end

class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friend, class_name: "User"
end
```

Comment: has_many `:extend` might be what you are looking for? see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-extensions

Answer (score 0):

If i'm reading what you're looking for correctly it seems that you are trying to do a join.

ActiveRecord supports eager loading through the includes call, which can also have conditions.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations

This I think would solve your issue.

Comment: actualy, join or include is not a problem - I'm just looking for some more elegant way of AR querying. thanks anyway :)